# Can I see remote terminal?

Tags: terminal, remote

I am running a C program in a Cent OS machine. Now, the lab is locked in this weekend, but I have access to another lab of the institute. I can access the files etc. via SSH from a Mac machine in the second lab, but I need to get access to the terminal (to see the output from the C program).

Answer (score 5):

The normal solutions for this would be to have started `tmux` or `screen` and start the C program from there. You could have attached to that from your `ssh` ession as well (and disconnect) without disrupting the program.

As you started this in a (graphical) terminal and not the console, you could use a VNC viewer to try and look at the current screen after running:

```
x11vnc -noxdamage -display :0 -safer -nopw -once -xrandr
```

Or if this is a one off, you could try to make a screenshot of the display and download the resulting file.

Next time just start the program under `tmux`, that is much quicker as it doesn't have to transmit graphical data (transmitting a picture costs you thousands of words).